# When button clicked update the database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter when I click the button I need to update the studentstatus field from 'PENDING' to 'ACTIVE'. But it isn't working. 
Table: studentstatus. 
Fields: acceptid, studentid, studentstatus

controller:

```
function updateStat (){
    $this->load->model("mdl_studentstatus");
    if ($this->input->post('mysubmit')) {
      $this->mdl_studentstatus->upddata($this->input->post());
   }
}
```

model:

```
public function upddata() {
     $this->db->set('studentstatus', 'ACCEPT', FALSE);
     $this->db->where('studentstatus', 'PENDING');
     $this->db->update('studentstatus');
     return true;
  }
```

view file:

```
<table>
     <tr>
      <td><strong>Student Id</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Student Status</strong></td>
    </tr> 
     <?php foreach($status as $stat){?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $stat->studentid;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $stat->studentstatus;?></td>
           <td> <fieldset class="submit_field">
              <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'ACCEPT'); ?>
           </fieldset></td>

      </tr>     
     <?php }?>  
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Controller

```
public function update()
{
    $this->load->model("mdl_studentstatus");
    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
      $query     = $this->mdl_studentstatus->upddata();
   }
}
```

In your Model

```
 public function upddata() {
        $this->db->where('studentstatus', 'PENDING');
        $query  =   $this->db->update(studentstatus ,array('studentstatus' => 'ACCEPT'));
        return true;
  }
```

This piece of code update all table where status is pending if you want to update a single row Use this snippet
 Controller

```
public function update()
{
   $this->load->model("mdl_studentstatus");
   if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
   $data = array('student_id' => $this->input->post('student_id'));
   $query     = $this->mdl_studentstatus->upddata($data);
  }
}
```

Model

```
public function upddata($data) {
    $this->db->where(array('studentstatus' => 'PENDING' , 'studen_id' => $data['studen_id']));
    $query =   $this->db->update(studentstatus ,array('studentstatus' => 'ACCEPT'));
    return true;
  }
```

In your View

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><strong>Student Id</strong></td>
  <td><strong>Student Status</strong></td>
</tr> 
 <?php foreach($status as $stat){?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $stat->studentid;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $stat->studentstatus;?></td>
       <td> <fieldset class="submit_field">
         <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $stat->studentid;?>" />  
          <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'ACCEPT'); ?>
       </fieldset></td>

  </tr>     
 <?php }?>
```

Comment: Let me know if any problem here

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I highly appreciate your effort... but still not updating the table

Comment: Can you tell me error have you debug the code in model or controller what is coming in print_r();